# Enable POST on IIS 7

Tags: iis-7

I have a WCF service that requires POST verb. This service is hosted in a ASP.NET application on IIS 7. I have successfully confirmed that GET works, but POST does not. I have the following two operations, GET works, POST does not.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/TestPost", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string TestPost()
{
  return "great";
}

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/TestGet", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string TestGet()
{
  return "great";
}
```

When I try to access TestPost, I receive a message that says: "Method not allowed".

Can someone help me configure IIS 7 to allow POST requests?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check your `<handlers/>` section in your WCF service config file to ensure that post verbs are accepted.